# Error in integrating ShareKit App iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sharekit

I want to use shareKit app in my project but when i m trying to post image on facebook i am getting this error .

```
Error: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily enable it, you may disable the "august 2012" platform migration. It will be disabled permanently on August 1, 2012.
```

i am using latest SDK or ShareKit.

Comment: where did this error appear? which file was it?

Comment: use the latest version of sharekit :)

Comment: i have downloaded the latest version

Comment: @lakesh when i m signing into facebook .

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use ShareKit to implement Facebook Integration. Use the new iOS 6 `SLComposeViewController` to post to Facebook

Here is the full code to post to Facebook

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) //check if Facebook Account is linked
    {
      mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]; 
                [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]];
       [mySLComposerSheet addImage:yourimage]; //an image you could post
        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        NSString *output;
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                output = @"Action Cancelled";
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                output = @"Post Successfull";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } 
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }];
```

Comment: No its not working in iOS5. For iOS5 you should have to implement share kit.

Comment: No this is only for iOS 6. But it makes it a whole lot easier

Comment: problem is i dont have iOS6

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the latest version. The latest version is: [ShareKit 2.0](http://github.com/sharekit/sharekit).

If you use Facebook, Twitter or SinaWeibo **with iOS6 only** it is really more straightforward to use social.network directly.